How do you calculate how long an iPad is supported? Is this similar to Android?
I am an Android user and I am looking into iPads.
In Android knowing till when Google supports security/software upgrades is important when making a decision on what phone to buy.
Is this relevant for Apple too? I was Googling and it seems that it is expected that one can keep an iPad at best case for around 5 years but I don't understand exactly what that means?
E.g. if I look at a 2022 model does that mean that Apple will support security/software updates till 2027? Or that a 2022 model if I buy it today it will last me for 5 years? I.e. usable until 2029?

Where in the world will you buy the iPad. The time of support varies longer in California than other US states and internationally it varies per local law.

@bmike: Will buy in Europe

I find Mactracker gives a rapid source of info: https://mactracker.ca

For iPads worst case is 5 to 6 years and best case, longer than that sometimes 9 years if they keep selling the model you choose for multiple years.
Apple officially offers service, repair and support for all equipment for 5 years after that model is withdrawn from sale, so if you buy the first iPad in a new line, you’ll get more than 5 and even the last iPad of a specific model gets a full 5 years of post sale support.
This is a very uniform policy and the only deviations I’ve ever seen is they give more time and not less.
iPadOS updates typically end soon after a model is obsolete, but Apple can and will do patches for old gear from time to time.

Products are considered vintage when Apple stopped distributing them for sale more than 5 and less than 7 years ago

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102772
Right now the “youngest” obsolete iPad is per Apple

iPad (6th generation) Wi-Fi and iPad (6th generation) Wi-Fi + Cellular

Wikipedia reports these dates for that model:

Release date March 27, 2018
Introductory price   $329 (and used, these are still priced $85 to $145 on US eBay today)
Discontinued September 10, 2019

Note iPadOS 18 doesn’t run on that iPad, but it could still get future iPadOS 17 updates for either function or security even after iPadOs 18 is released. This happened with iPadOS 17.7.3 on December 11, 2024.

I think in your answer you are covering aspects of HW durability, repairs/service and regular SW updates (for getting latest cool functionality). Because my usage in general is basic, I am more interested in security updates. As an example lets say today one buys a Apple iPad (2022) 10.9 inch 64GB with IPadOS 16 if I understand correctly the support/repairs and software & security updates will be until Oct. 2027? And what does apple do for security updates prior that date or for older models in general? E.g. zero day vulnerability
